# Salesforce Site: Lookup not finding results

Tags: force.com-sites

I am trying to get an external site to work and it has a lookup to the account object. The search box appears but it will not find any results.

The Site Public Access Settings has access to the the object and all the fields. Also the Site Standard Page lookup page has been added.

Any ideas?

Comment: Only thing I can think is the lookup filed has a filter on it which is filtering out the records?

Comment: We figured it out. When playing with Communities recently we set the account external sharing rules to private. Moving them to read only fixed this issue.

Comment: You should post your text as an answer and mark it as the right one. that way others coming to this question can get the answer

Comment: Thanks, I posted it as an Answer. I will mark it as the right answer in 2 days when it lets me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out. When playing with Communities recently we set the account external sharing rules to private. Moving them to read only fixed this issue.